# Parse Client API Key causes CORS exception in Angular app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, parse-platform, cors, angular-resource

I have create an app that uses the Parse.com rest API. I've created a factory using $resource that defines a get with the required parse.com headers.

When I run this app with the parse headers X-Parse-REST-API-Key it works as expected but when I use X-Parse-Client-Key the application throws a CORS error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Games. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

These headers work with client key on Chrome's Postman. I've also checked config.xml to ensure  `<access origin="*" /`>

I want to use the client key because Parse documentation warns against using the rest-api key on clients...

Comment: the cors exception is generated by server and not client.. so mostly the server is parsing the http header you are sending.. get in touch with the parse.com to check the correct header name

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the Rest key instead of the client key as I cannot change the setup of the parse.com service!

Comment: It's pretty sad to use Rest for that.  I have the same issue. Since May, you haven't found any cleaner alternatives?